# Get JSON from two URLs and echo data from each (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I've got multiple JSON API URLs I'm attempting to pull data from. They are all structured the same but with data from different locations. I'm trying to get each file and echo the data from them in a table. I've managed to get it to work when I just pull the data from each file separately and repeat the code for each TR, but I"m attempting to have it loop in the way it would as if pulling rows of data from a MySQL database, so it'll show on the front end the data from each location in a separate row of the table.

JSON File Structure

---

```
 {
      "Altimeter": "3005",      
      "Flight-Rules": "VFR", 
      "Raw-Report": "KJFK 241851Z 19009KT 10SM CLR 31/18 A3005 RMK AO2 SLP174 T03060183", 
      "Station": "KJFK", 
      "Visibility": "10", 
      "Wind-Direction": "190", 
      "Wind-Gust": "", 
      "Wind-Speed": "09", 
  }
```

---

I've managed to get this to work for one single station via the code below:

```
<?
$json = file_get_contents('Station_1_URL');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $decoded['Station']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $decoded['Flight-Rules']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $decoded['Wind-Direction']; ?> @ <? echo $decoded['Wind-Speed']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $decoded['Altimeter']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like it to gather the data from two stations and output like below

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr> <!-- This is data from the first station -->
                <td><? echo $decoded['Station']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Flight-Rules']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Wind-Direction']; ?> @ <? echo $decoded['Wind-Speed']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Altimeter']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> <!-- This is data from the next station -->
                <td><? echo $decoded['Station']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Flight-Rules']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Wind-Direction']; ?> @ <? echo $decoded['Wind-Speed']; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $decoded['Altimeter']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of all station URLs you need to travers and wrap frontend in `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
$station_urls = ['Station_1_URL', 'Station_2_URL', 'Station_3_URL'];
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <? foreach ($station_urls as $station_url) :
        $json = file_get_contents($station_url);
        $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $decoded['Station']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $decoded['Flight-Rules']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $decoded['Wind-Direction']; ?> @ <? echo $decoded['Wind-Speed']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $decoded['Altimeter']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put your station URLs in an array

```
<?php
  $stationURLs = array(Station_1_URL, Station_2_URL, ...);
  foreach ($stationURLs as $stationURL) {
    // fetch the JSON response
    // print the <tr>
    // (same as your chunk of code for station1)
  }
?>
```